# Get specific xml child node using variable SQL

Tags: sql, xml, xquery

i need to get specific value of child node in my xml inside a while. 
I have a xml with various tags of 'DangerAlrt' and i need to get the 'Title' and 'Message' value while index has a specific value.

i mean. this is my xml

```
Declare @myxml xml ='<Shipment>
                  <InfoAlerts>
                    <InfoAlert>
                      <Title>Workflow Instance Id</Title>
                      <Message>59c541de-b8c6-4e5a-884f-14a68816763c</Message>
                    </InfoAlert>
                  </InfoAlerts>
                  <SuccessAlerts>
                    <SuccessAlert>
                      <Title>Schema Validation</Title>
                      <Message>Ok</Message>
                    </SuccessAlert>
                  </SuccessAlerts>
                  <WarningAlerts />
                  <DangerAlerts>
                    <DangerAlert>
                      <Title>Valid City Name</Title>
                      <Message>Error</Message>
                    </DangerAlert>
                    <DangerAlert>
                      <Title>Valid something</Title>
                      <Message>Error2</Message>
                    </DangerAlert>
                  </DangerAlerts>
                 </Shipment>'
```

if i need a specific node:

```
select @myxml.query('data(//DangerAlert/Message)')
```

Good, but that returns me all values of 'Message' inside 'DangerAlert'.

now, i can return specific value of 'Message' with:

```
select @myxml.query('data(//DangerAlert/Message)[1]') -- show me:  Error
```

or

```
select @myxml.query('data(//DangerAlert/Message)[2]') -- show me:  Error2
```

Great!, but, when i have many nodes of 'DangerAlert' i use this sentence inside a while

```
select @myxml.query('data(//DangerAlert/Message)[local-name() = sql:variable("@i")]') -- where 'i' is the variable (converted to string) used to iterate
```

but doesn't work. retunrs me nothing :( 
how to use a sql variable as index value into this expression ?

Answer (score 0):

`data()` is not necessary (and almost never is). You are referencing the SQL variable correctly, but `local-name()` returns the element name, not the element value.

If you want to match `<DangerAlert>` where its child `<Message>` matches your variable:

```
select @myxml.query('//DangerAlert[Message = sql:variable("@i")]')
```

**Update:** In comments you have made it clear that you only intended to iterate over the `<Title>` values, not match on the DangerAlert/Message value. In that case, it would be more efficient to simply return all Titles, instead of forcing iteration in SQL.

```
select @myxml.query('//DangerAlert/Title')
```

If the purpose of the iterator is to limit the number of values returned, then you can do that more efficiently - in a single query - with this XPath:

```
select @myxml.query('//DangerAlert[fn:number() le sql:variable("@max-results")]/Title')
```

Also note that if you intend to return a string, then use `string()` not `data()`:

`data(//DangerAlert/Title)` => `//DangerAlert/Title/string()`

Comment: Why is not necessary to use data() ?. and second thing, your solutions doesn't work. because i need the value node while the variable @i iterates. However, with a change to your response, I got the answer i was looking for :)  @myxml.query('data(//DangerAlert/Title)[sql:variable("@i")]'))

Comment: @Makito The query you provided in comments is not correct; it will return all `<Title>` values for any non-empty SQL variable value. `data()` simply atomizes the value you give it, which is often either redundant or at worst has unintended side effects. Best practices are to not use it unless you know you need it.

Comment: How.... ? its not correct ? why ?. i need the value, not the node. although your answer still doesn't work for me reply. I explain. 
It may be correct to say that the way I get the value is not the most appropriate and efficient. but.... Why not work for me? try this (i use the same xml in the question): declare @k INT
SET @k = 2 -- Change K value for 1, 2, etc...for many 'DangerAlert' as  have the xml
Select @myxml.query('data(//DangerAlert/Title)[sql:variable("@k")]') as BadThing,
  @myxml.query('//DangerAlert[Title = sql:variable("@k")]') as Goothing                       you understand me?

Comment: @Makito I see what you are trying to do now. You never intended to select based on the error message, but you want to iterate over each error title. In that case, iterating in SQL is unnecessary. See my updated answer.

Comment: i see that you understand me much better... but (excuse me for being so insistent). I needed to get the value of the title and message of each error. (no matter how many have). So I'm iterating with a "while" (how many errors have) for each data separately, not together. so, while iterating, I returned the title and message corresponding to analyzed "DangerAlert". so, thats why i use the iterative structure "while". again, it may not be as efficient or best way, but it works with Select @ myxml.query ('data (// DangerAlert / Title) [sql: variable (" @ k ")]') there is a best way to do this?

Comment: @Makito Iterating in SQL is not necessary. The only reason you think you need `while` is because you use `data()`, which prematurely converts your values to strings. It would be much less confusing to select the XML elements you want first, and then convert them to strings as a final step.